# Configuring OpenOCD debug on VSCODE with the Raspberry Pico as a target using the Debug-Probe - No working solution found

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks, raspberry-pi-pico

I have been pulling my hair out trying to configure VSCode on MacOS to support the above mention configuration.
The debugging works on the command line: I started the OpenOCD server in a separate terminal window like this:

*sudo openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/rp2040.cfg -c "adapter speed 5000"*

Which starts fine and recognises the debug probe.

In a terminal window within VSCode I select the PICO examples build/blink directory and I start the debugger:

*arm-none-eabi-gdb blink.elf*

and I can happily set breakpoints etc. So the basic setup works, and the targets built by VSCode are proper.

However, to get visual debugging within the GUI fails. I have tried various variations of '*launch.json*', '*settings.json*' and '*tasks.json*' but none seem to work.

The variations I found on the various sites are all similar, but none of them are functional. I also tried variations of json files in the 'ide/vscode' as distributed but **no** succes..

I am using VSCode Version on MacOS Monterey 12.6.7:
1.79.2 (Universal)
Commit: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
Date: 2023-06-14T08:58:52.392Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 21.6.0

Does anybody have this working on a system similar to mine? If so, what are the settings in the json files.

I did install *OpenOCD for MacOS* (chipcode-nl.picoprobe-mac) as well, but that does not seems to be very functional. As I explained above, the basis setup for OpenOCD from the command line works...

Comment: Did you install the "Cortex-debug" VSCode plugin and set it up?

Comment: No, I did not not, at least not in this workspace. I added it and it works now, with some mods

Comment: So solved, but do not know how to award the bounty.. :-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install "Cortex-debug" is the answer. Thanks to hcheung